# Is there any way to configure disk store for terracotta BigMemory to remove all data store on service/cache manager start up?

Tags: java, ehcache, terracotta, ehcache-bigmemory

Question relative to terracotta BigMemory GO configuration

Q: Is there any way to configure disk store to remove all data store on service/cache manager start up ?

Description: I have BigMemory configure with overflow to OffHeap, so Lucene index would be created in disk store (not depended on persistent strategy). I need to have disk store cleaned on next cache manager start up (application start up), but I do not want to have specific clean up method in my application code. 
Currently if after should down was successful index would be reused by BigMemory on next start up.

Thank you.

Comment: not sure i understand your question...First is it BigMemory GO? Max (meaning terracotta distributed)? Then, what sort of "index" are you referring to? Overflow to offheap does not create anything on disk...offheap data is stored in RAM. The only index i can think of is related to cache "searching", which does use an index...or you're referring to index regarding terracotta "permanent store" to disk?...plz provide more details about these so we can answer better...

Comment: I am talking about BigMemory GO. Index- lucian index created by bigmemory in case you are using overflowToOffHeap, it is stored under disk store location that could be configured or default location would be used.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to remove the Index data from BigMemory Go on restart.

Whether you can do this or not depends on your persistence strategy. If it is local restartable, BigMemory Go will try to either reuse the index data if the application was shutdown cleanly, or it will recover the indexes if it was shutdown abruptly. So, for a persistence strategy of local restartable, there is no way to avoid rebuilding the data.

If your persistence strategy is "localTempswap", then you will not rebuild any data on restart and will lose the application's state.

Please see here for more information: http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/fast-restart

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am talking about NONE persistence strategy in case off heap is used, disk store is created by Lucian index